# Custom Sorting algorithm (C)

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

Our teacher asked us today to make a custom sorting algorithm, and he gave us some instructions, however I wasn't able to solve it:
First you get the smallest number from a randomly generated array and assign it to a separate array. Then you get the second smallest number the array and assign it to the next position in the separate array.

I was able to build this, but it doesn't fully work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define ANZAHL 5

int main() {
    srand(time(0));
    int zfeld[ANZAHL], zfeld1[ANZAHL] = {}, zfeld2[ANZAHL] = {}, i, d, ug, og, kl = ANZAHL + 1;
    printf("Gib die untere und obere grenze an");
    scanf("%d%d", &ug, &og);
    for (i = 0; i < ANZAHL; i++) {
        zfeld[i] = rand() % ((og - ug) - 1) + ug + 1;
    }
    for (d = 0; d < ANZAHL; d++) {
        for (i = 0; i < ANZAHL; i++) {
            if (zfeld[i] < kl && zfeld[i] != zfeld2[d - 1]) {
                kl = zfeld[i];
            }
        }
        zfeld2[d] = kl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Step through the program with a debugger or add a bunch of debug outputs and see where the program deviates from your expectations. That'll probably be a bug.

Comment: For small programs you can also use a pencil and paper. Pretend to be the computer. Run the program yourself. Does it sort the numbers? Why not?

Comment: Well i know what the program does right now i just dont know how to get it to to do what i want.

Comment: If you know what it does and you know what you want and those differ, where exaclty is the difference? You did not tell us you know, the only thing you provide is "it doesnt fully work". With a problem description that precise you can only hope for an equally precise answer " Work hard to find out." Explain more. Provide sample input. Show the output for that. Show the different expected output. And then still describe what that difference is. And if you understand what the program does (as you stated) then explain what it does where and when which might be involved.

Comment: This looks like it wants to be an un-optimised heap sort, but pay careful attention to ones indices.

Comment: The fun part of @Yunnosch 's suggestion is writing down all of the "I have this, I want this" stuff often shakes  the logjam in the brain loose and you have a "Oh <expletive deleted> I'm so stupid!" moment. [Rubber Duck Debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) has a similar effect.

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same result.

Comment: Please post code that (with warnings enabled) cleanly compiles.  Some of the problems with the code are: *untitled1.c:9:41: warning: ISO C forbids empty initializer braces [-Wpedantic]*   The compiler will produce some kind of 'workaround' but that does not mean the workaround is correct.

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) please follow that axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: regarding: `zfeld[i] = rand() % ((og - ug) - 1) + ug + 1;`  the variables `og` and `ug` are not initialized.  The result is undefined behavior.   Note: windows, in development/debug mode, will zero out the stack, but you should never depend on that feature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several issues:

- `kl=ANZAHL+1`: the length of the original array has nothing to do with *values*. It would make more sense to do `kl = og`. But still, the place where you do this assignment is wrong. Once you have found the first minimum value, `kl` will be too small to detect the *next* smallest value: you need to reset it each time you iterate in the outer loop.
- The inner loop should not iterate over *all* elements when you have already identified a few small values. You try to avoid to pick the same one twice, but just comparing with the previously identified value (`zfeld[i] != zfeld2[d-1]`) is not going to work. First, because when `d` is zero, this is an invalid reference, and second: there are in general more values in `zfeld2` which you *also* don't want to select again. Instead consider that the first array should become "shorter". You can do this by moving the last value of the array into the slot where you found the smallest value. Then you can consider that the array became one unit smaller without losing any information. To make that work, you need to know the *index* where you find the smallest value.

So here is the corrected code for the loops:

```
for(d=0; d<ANZAHL; d++)
{
    // Reset the index, and just consider the first value to the the smallest so far
    int indexOfSmallest = 0;
    // Each time you move one value, we look at one value less in this loop:
    for(i=1; i<ANZAHL - d; i++)
    {
        if(zfeld[i] < zfeld[indexOfSmallest])
        {
            indexOfSmallest = i;
        }
    }
    zfeld2[d] = zfeld[indexOfSmallest];
    // Move last value in the slot that opens up:
    zfeld[indexOfSmallest] = zfeld[ANZAHL - d - 1];
}
```

NB: this is a variant to [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort). Selection sort does not use a second array, as it reuses the space that is liberated in the first array to store the sorted values.

I would also suggest to use better variable names. Names like `kl`, `ug`, `og` are maybe clear to you, but it is better practice to just use full names: `kleinste`, `untereGrenze`, ...etc.

Comment: Also note that the generation formula is incorrect too: `zfeld[i] = rand() % ((og - ug) - 1) + ug + 1;` will generate numbers in the range `(ug+1)..(og-1)`. The value `ug` should probably be included, which is easy to achieve with `zfeld[i] = rand() % (og - ug + 1) + ug;`